# Selenium fails with latest ChromeDriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm running:

- Windows 8 Enterprise 64-bit
- Chrome Version  32.0.1700.76 m
- Chromedriver v2.8

I got the problem that every time I am running my test case I get the error message:

```
[1396:8756:0129/110336:ERROR:gpu_info_collector_win.cc(102)] Can't retrieve a va
lid WinSAT assessment.
[1396:8756:0129/110336:ERROR:chrome_views_delegate.cc(176)] NOT IMPLEMENTED
[1396:8756:0129/110336:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(746)] NOT IMPLEMENT
ED
[1396:8756:0129/110336:ERROR:desktop_root_window_host_win.cc(746)] NOT IMPLEMENT
ED
```

I tried to google it for a while and it seems that this is a common error when ChromeDriver is outdated, but I am using the latest version of ChromeDriver and the latest version of Chrome, so this should work. Does someone have an idea?!
Thanks!

Comment: Please update your OS if it is not updated. Also give a try to the lower version of Chromedriver. example 2.7

Comment: Thanks but I updated my OS, and tried ChromeDriver2.6/2.7/2.8 but I still get the same errors.

Comment: You may need to look for the path where your project retrieves the chromedriver from, and replace that one.

Comment: Thanks,actually the path of Chrome itself was wrong, unfortunately this didn't fix the problem. The system variables for the chromedriver  should be all fine. I tried different paths and variables but it didn't change the result.